# cursorLoader in androidstudio

Tags: java, android, android-cursorloader

I'm a super beginner so I'm just following some project and I knew that startActivityforResult has been deprecated, so I changed the code by using ActivityResultLauncher. But I don't know how to fix CursorLoader error. Can you tell me how to fix it?

So the original code was this.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        
        if(requestCode == PICK_PROFILE_FROM_ALBUM && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
            


            Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            //image path
            String photoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);

           
    }
```

This is the current code

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    
                    if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
                       

                        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                        int column_index =cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        
                        String photoPath = cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
```

So the context in CursorLoader should be fixed. It needs 'Context' but it is ActivityResultCallback now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is typical situation in long running Projects that sometimes You will need to migrate Your existing code base to newer API.

About CursorLoader. If `startActivityResult` Launcher is field inside your Activity
This line

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
```

can be replaced with

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(YourActivityClass.this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
```

I also see that cursor is loaded on UI Thread and it can have an impact on performance

Comment: oh okay thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `this` keyword in this case is as it should, referring to the current context and the current context is the anonymous class,i.e. instance of `ActivityResultCallback` but the `CursorLoader` needs a reference to the instance of `Context` or `Activity`. The simple fix in this case is to append `.this` to the name of your class or activity

Say your `Activity` is `MainActivity`, so this

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
```

will turn to this

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MainActivity.this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Well explained @gtxtreme

Comment: I agree, this should be the accepted answer, anyways, glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing **this** directly write **youractivityname.this**

Assuming your activity name to be MainActivity this is how you should be passing context:

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MainActivity.this, data.getData(), proj, null, null, null);
```